# android pass viewmodel instance to another class function

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel

is it possible to do this, if not, why:

1. I pass through the arguments new parcelable class to the fragment
2. When I click on the button in the UI, I pass the viewmodel instance to the function of this class and immediately call the functions I need from the viewmodel in the same place.

```
@Parcelize
class ClassA {
 fun onClick(viewModel: FragmentViewModel) {
   viewModel.callJob()
 }
}
```

Comment: i don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with this, but also i don't understand why you're trying to do this, could you perhaps explain the problem you're trying to solve as well

Comment: @a_local_nobody i need reuse some screen with viewModel, they look same, but network request different